# Passing parameter to Onsen service

Tags: angularjs, onsen-ui

I'm clearly missing something basic with onsen/angular, but I'm unclear on how I can pass a parameter into a service that's querying a DB. It's all fine when I hardcode the query instead of using the 'id' parameter:

```
.factory('Inscription', function(DB) {
    var self = this;

    self.all = function(id) {
            return DB.query('SELECT * FROM inscription where project_id = ? limit 100', [3])
            .then(function(result){
                    return DB.fetchAll(result);
            });
    };
```

but I'm not sure how to dynamically pass the id parameter to this query. The relevant controller code is:

```
.controller('InscriptionsCtrl', function($scope, Inscription) {
    $scope.inscriptions = [];
    $scope.inscription = null;
    // Get all the project inscriptions
    Inscription.all().then(function(inscriptions) {
            $scope.inscriptions = inscriptions;
    });
```

which is used in a list:

```
 <ons-template id="showProject.html">
   <ons-page>
      <ons-list ng-controller="InscriptionsCtrl">
        <ons-list-item ng-repeat="inscription in inscriptions" ng-click="navi.pushPage('showInscription.html')">
            {{inscription.title}} - {{inscription.description | limitTo:50}}...
        </ons-list-item>
      </ons-list>
   </ons-page>
 </ons-template>
```

That page with the list is being passed the project id to use in the DB query:

$scope.ons.navigator.pushPage('showProject.html', {project_id: id});

I'm just not sure how to pass that id to the controller to form the right query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameters you use when pushing a page will be bound to the page object.

In the controller of the pushed page you can do:

```
var id = myNavigator.getCurrentPage().options.project_id;

Inscription.all(id).then(function(result) ...
```